# Find the value of t?

Tags: number-theory

> If $$t = \frac{200 \choose 100}{4^{100}}$$ then $t =$ ?

- (A) $t < \frac{1}{3}$
- (B) $\frac{1}{3} < t < \frac{1}{2}$
- (C) $\frac{1}{2} < t < \frac{2}{3}$
- (D) $\frac{2}{3} < t < 1$

Comment: I think it is $$t<\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Solution approach?

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: If ${200 \choose 100}$ is $x$ then I am getting $\frac{x}{..+x+..}$. Now how can I get two more $x$ and $+$ something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

> $$4^{100}=2^{200}=(1+1)^{200}=\sum_{k=0}^{200}\binom{200}{k}$$

Comment: Ironic, he could help others, but not himself

Comment: @SomeGuy What do you mean?

Comment: Its a joke about your name haha